# Is it possible to do an 'if' statement to change the navbar just for my allauth templates?

Tags: python, django

Right now my navbar has an 'if' statement for being authenticated vs not authenticated. My allauth templates are extending from my base and showing these navbars.

Is it possible to add in another 'if' statement for when a user is on an allauth form?

Right now my navbar looks something like this...

```py
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ml-2 mr-1">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="navbar-brand d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle ml-1 mr-0" href="{% url 'home' %}">

             blah blah blah

            {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link orange" href="{% url 'management' %}">Site Management</a></li>

                    blah blah blah

            {% endif %}    


        {% else %}      
            <a class="navbar-brand d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle ml-2 mr-0" href="{% url 'home' %}">

            blah blah blah
 
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: When you added the new if condition you're asking about, did it work?

Comment: I didn't add a new one yet. I wouldn't even know how to phrase it. I only want to change the navbar on a couple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inheritance](https://svn.python.org/projects/external/Jinja-1.1/docs/build/inheritance.html) and define a variable in a parent template together with a block you'll extend in your child template.

For example:

```
# parent

This is my parent
{% set in_all_auth = True %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
This is end of my parent

# child

Here I extend the child by the parent content    
{% extends "parent.txt" %}
This is overriding the "content" block from a parent template
{% block content %}
{% if in_all_auth %}
in all auth
{% else %}
not in all auth
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
Here the block ends
```

Running:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
>>> env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
>>> print(env.get_template("child.txt").render())
Here I extend the child by the parent content    
This is my parent



in all auth


This is end of my parent
>>>
```

For trimming the space you may utilize the `-` operator and for not displaying the parent contents you may use additional blocks to disable it with variables.

Or, you can simply extend the rendering by another variable in which you'll set if a user is in the all auth form manually from Python itself.